# Bootstrap 3 Create inline select within heading

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to achieve something like this:[image: Inline Select within heading] , I'm trying to make it work for several hours but couldn't do so,Here is my Code:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-mid-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1 col-mid-5 col-lg-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-7">
                        <h5>Land Area</h5></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <select class="form-control" id="mainSearch-unitSelect">
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions to make it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

https://jsfiddle.net/2bz3jpad/2/

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-mid-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1 col-mid-5 col-lg-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
                    <h5><strong>Land Area:</strong></h5></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 text-left">
                        <select class="form-control" id="mainSearch-unitSelect">
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you noticed my top columns where i am trying to fit my this inline 'form-group' , its pretty small , select get too small , but i want it to be like in the picture how could i do that ?

Comment: i'm not getting you. What you actually want can you tell me.

Comment: notice the spaces between each element in give snapshot ? , columns have usually greater padding than this in bootstrap , is there any workaround for that , this is i am asking

Comment: yes this is it, thanks , so we can change padding of columns ? it will not affect responsiveness ?

Answer (score -1):

Narrow your label's column and float the text to the right.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-mid-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1 col-mid-5 col-lg-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <h5 class="pull-right">Land Area</h5></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-7">
                        <select class="form-control" id="mainSearch-unitSelect">
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### EDIT

Or use an inline form:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline